# How to properly make POST request

Tags: r, http

I'm trying to make my first POST request to an API. For some reason, I always get status 403 in return. I suspect it's the signature that is being incorrectly generated. The api-key and client id is for sure correct.

My code

```
nonce <-as.integer(Sys.time())

post_message <- paste0(nonce, data_client.id, data_key) # data_client.id = client id # data_key = key

sha.message <- toupper(digest::hmac(data_secret, object = post_message, algo = 'sha256', serialize = TRUE))

url <- 'https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/balance/'


body = list('API-KEY' = data_key, 'nonce' = nonce, 'signature' = sha.message)

httr::POST(url, body = body, verbose())
```

Output

```
<- HTTP/1.1 403 Authentication Failed
```

I'm trying to access the Bitstamp API: https://www.bitstamp.net/api/?package=Rbitcoin&version=0.9.2

> All private API calls require authentication. For a successful
>   authentication you need to provide your API key, a signature and a
>   nonce parameter.
>
> API KEY
>
> To get an API key, go to "Account", "Security" and then "API Access".
>   Set permissions and click "Generate key".
>
> NONCEN
>
> once is a regular integer number. It must be increased with every
>   request you make. Read more about it here. Example: if you set nonce
>   to 1 in your first request, you must set it to at least 2 in your
>   second request. You are not required to start with 1. A common
>   practice is to use unix time for that parameter.
>
> SIGNATURE
>
> Signature is a HMAC-SHA256 encoded message containing nonce, customer
>   ID (can be found here) and API key. The HMAC-SHA256 code must be
>   generated using a secret key that was generated with your API key.
>   This code must be converted to it's hexadecimal representation (64
>   uppercase characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your question is still standing, but based on your code, I managed to get it working. In fact, the main problem is in the body, the API documentation shows it expects 'key' instead of 'API-KEY'. 
Also, serialize should be FALSE instead of TRUE.

At the moment this works (but the API may change):

```
nonce <-as.integer(Sys.time())

post_message <- paste0(nonce, data_client.id, data_key) # data_client.id = client id # data_key = key

sha.message <- toupper(digest::hmac(data_secret, object = post_message, algo = 'sha256', serialize = FALSE))

url <- 'https://www.bitstamp.net/api/v2/balance/'

body = list('key' = data_key, 'nonce' = nonce, 'signature' = sha.message)

httr::POST(url, body = body, verbose())
```